# Having trouble with modules when converting .py to a .exe using cx_Freeze

Tags: python, cx-freeze

I am using Python 3.6.

I have really been learning to program the last few days and I want to send this program to a few people. They are not computer literate so I figured I would turn the program in to a windows executable for them.

I have done this before ages ago, but with simpler programs. My current program uses praw, sqlite3, urllib, os, time, and hurry.filesize.

I have my setup.py configured with the following code:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None


executables = [Executable("Image Downloader v2.py", base=base)]

packages = ["idna","praw","queue","hurry.filesize"]
options = {
    'build_exe': {

        'packages':packages,
    },

}

setup(
    name = "Reddit Image Downloader",
    options = options,
    version = "2.0",
    description = 'Downloads images from Reddit.',
    executables = executables
)
```

When I run `python setup.py build` from my command line, I get the error "no module named 'hurry.filesize'". I tried changing `hurry.filesize` in setup.py to just `hurry` and I get the same error as before, telling me that there is no module named "hurry". I also had to include the "queue" module in setup.py even though it's not part of my program because when I tried to build the executable I kept getting the module error but for "queue". Putting it in that list seems to have fixed that error.

How can I fix this?